# Why does firebase-appcheck-debug-testing fail to build under SDK version 31?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-check

When I try to build my app which relies upon Firebase App Check and the debug provider under SDK version 31, as required by Google Play, I get a Manifest merger error_:

```
Warning:
    Package name 'com.google.android.play.core.client' used in: com.google.android.play:integrity:1.0.1, com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1.

AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is amateur hour over at Google, the `firebase-appcheck-debug-testing` dep has a dependency on `androidx.test:core:1.2.0`. It's not until `1.5.0` that we get `android:exported` set properly on the necessary manifest elements. Thus, any project reliant on `firebase-appcheck-debug-testing` will not build under `targetSdkVersion 31`.

```
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug-testing -> 16.1.0
|    +--- androidx.test:core:1.2.0
```

You can see this if you download the POM directly from the Maven repo:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>androidx.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

It is unclear to me why `firebase-appcheck-debug-testing` has not had an update to correct this. I guess they do suggest never using the `DebugAppCheckProviderFactory` in production, and this is one way to achieve that (whilst also preventing building the app locally)!

To work around the problem, manually force version 1.5.0 in your `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'androidx.test:core:1.5.0'
```